# Cannot use my new field in a different namespace

Tags: c#, class, namespaces, syntax-error, field

I am trying to add a field in my class and to use it in an other namespace. I am modifying an existing c# project so the class has already fields that are used in the other namespace.

Here is the code of my class which is written on my namespace called 'ModeleDeDomaine':

```
namespace ModeleDeDomaine
{
      public class AlgorithmeGestionDesDouelles
      {
        public bool enCours;
        public bool Pasedff;
      }
}
```

The first field, 'enCours', was already created when I start working on this code. The second one is the one that I am trying to add.

Here is an extract of my code in my namespace 'IHM':

```
namespace IHM
{
  public MainWindow() {
       if (AlgorithmeGestionDesDouelles.enCours) {
        ...
       }
  }
}
```

I have no error when compiling it, the syntax seems to be correct.
But if I write the same thing but with the other field:

```
namespace IHM
{
     public MainWindow() {

           if (AlgorithmeGestionDesDouelles.Pasedff) {
           ...
           }
      }
 }
```

I have the following syntax error:

> Error CS1061: 'AlgorithmeGestionDesDouelles' does not contain a definition for 'Pasedff' and no extension method 'Pasedff' accepting a first argument of type 'AlgorithmeGestionDesDouelles' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Why can't I use my field in this namespace?

Thank you in advance for all of your answers,

Coline

Comment: try doing clean to your solution and build again! if it doesn't work, make sure you don't have duplicate classes with the name `AlgorithmeGestionDesDouelles`, perhaps you are using the wrong class.

Comment: Thank you, I cleaned it but the error persists. I looked again but there is no other class with the same name in the project, when I put the cursor on the call of the 'enCours' field, it precise that it is from ModeleDeDomaine

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `AlgorithmeGestionDesDouelles.enCours` suggests this is a *static* field and can be referenced (called) without an *instance*. This, however, does *not* follow from the code example you provide: it is an *instance field*.

If you change the field you added to `public static bool Pasedff;`, the code in your `main` should compile. I cannot tell whether that is something you want though.

Here's some info on static classes that maybe useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members